# Tensorflow object detection API minimum score threshold

Tags: object, tensorflow, detection

I'm running detection with the Tensorflow Object Detection API with the default model and I'd just like to print the detection scores to the console.

For example `object_detection_tutorial.ipynb` has a function called `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` that draws bounding boxes on the image. This function has a parameter `min_score_thresh=.5` and if you change it it draws bounding boxes for everything above that threshold.

i'm not visualizing the images though, just want to print out the score for anything > `0.2` but I can't find a way to specify this?

Currently it's only printing to the console detections with scores above `.5` which i guess is the default?

Comment: Looks like you want to query based on scores, following is code you can use on output_dict for index, value in enumerate(output_dict['detection_classes'][0]):
          if(scores[index] > 0.2):
              if((category_index.get(value)).get('name').encode('utf8') == b'person'):
                  print("Car exists at Index,value : ",index, value)
                  personExists = True
      print("person Exists: {} ",personExists)

Answer (score 2):

`visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` method has a parameter `min_score_thresh`. you can pass your threshold values as `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(min_score_thresh=.2)`.

Its default values is set to 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to query based on scores, following is code you can use on output_dict

```
 for index, value in enumerate(output_dict['detection_classes'][0]):
          if(scores[index] > **0.2**):
              if((category_index.get(value)).get('name').encode('utf8') == b'person'):
                  print("Car exists at Index,value : ",index, value)
                  personExists = True[![enter image description here][1]][1]
      print("person Exists: {} ",personExists)
```

Code here if formatting above is not clear:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to utils/visualization_utils.py and find visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array() and change the default value of min_score_thresh to whatever you want. By default, the value is 0.5.

Comment: You can just set the argument "min_score_thresh" when calling the function, "visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array". It's such less messy than changing the definition of the function itself.